# Router failed CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, router

http://localhost/index

but connect to http://localhost/abc...xyz => THIS WILL BE ERROR PAGE SYSTEM

after, i want connect to http://localhost/index

Answer (score 0):

Unable to understand . Please describe properly.

You may update **Config/routes.php**

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
/**
 * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to a controller called 'Pages',
 * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
 * to use (in this case, src/Template/Pages/index.ctp)...
 */
   $routes->connect('/index', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index']);
}
```

Comment: example 
$routes->connect('/index', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index']);
=> localhost/index.... but user enter localhost/indexxxx.. =>  THIS WILL BE ERROR PAGE SYSTEM.... i want if error then redirect to $routes->connect('/index', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index']);

Comment: Cake\Controller\Exception\MissingActionException will be raised. You can either catch this exception yourself and redirect to home page, or allow CakePHP exception.